# <c:out> in jsp for hidden type

Tags: jsp, jstl

Which of the following syntax is correct?

```
<input type="hidden"  name="outagetkt" value="<c:out value='${ppshOutageAttrib.attributeHM['OutageType']}'></c:out>"/>

<input type="hidden"  name="outagetkt" value="<c:out value="${ppshOutageAttrib.attributeHM['OutageType']}"></c:out>"/>
```

When I used 'double quotes' before '$' with escape char like this:

```
<input type="hidden"  name="outagetkt" value="<c:out value=\"${ppshOutageAttrib.attributeHM['OutageType']}\"></c:out>"/>
```

This did not work..Can any one tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: What happens when you try them?

Comment: <input name="outagetkt" value="DST&quot;></c:out>........ This is the output

Comment: The output of which one of your two syntaxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to `<c:out>` you could use the `fn:escapeXml()` function:

```
<input type="hidden" name="outagetkt" value="${fn:escapeXml(ppshOutageAttrib.attributeHM['OutageType'])}" />
```

That would remove the need for the nested `<c:out>` and reduce the number of quotes.

For that you'd need to specify the functions tag library directive in your JSP if you hadn't already.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```